# How to copy a file in a git tree?

Tags: git

I've just started learning git and I can't really find the answer to this.

What does it mean copying a (`.config`) file into the git tree?

Do I have to copy it, into the `.git` directory or something else?

Later edit: I am supposed to duplicate my distro, so I have to copy one of the `config-*` files visible with `ls /boot` in a `.config` file in my `git` tree.

On [Linux Kernel Newbies](http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelBuild) I found:

> **Duplicating your current config**

If you're trying to see if a bug is fixed, you probably want to duplicate the configuration on your running kernel. That config file is stored somewhere in /boot/. There might be several files that start with config, so you want the one associated with your running kernel. You can find that by running uname -a and finding the config file that ends with your kernel version number. Copy that file into the source directory as .config. Or just run this command:

`cp /boot/config-`uname -r`* .config`

> 

Will this work if I changed the directory to be /git or does this not make sense at all?

Comment: *copying a (`.config`) file into the git tree*... Did you read that somewhere on the Web? If so, please edit your question to add a link. It would be nice for us to read the relevant passage in context.

Comment: Sorry @Jubobs, I was trying to follow the steps a friend suggested, so no link.

Comment: What you mean by "my git tree" is unclear. Are you referring to a specific Git repository? If so, What's the purpose of that repository?

Comment: I agree it is unclear, these are the instructions I received and the lack of clarity is one of the reasons I asked the question. I went with `cp /boot/config-uname -r* .config` before reading Tiki-Web's final answer; if I run into trouble or learn that it's a wrong way, I'll start over and follow the directions received here. Thank you for your comments, @Jubobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the Git config file or something else ? You should never write directly into the .git directory. Instead you interact with it using Git commands.
In general, adding a file to the tree means :
- committing the file
- pushing it to the right branch.

```
git add relative-path/file
git commit -m 'some comment'
git push yourbranch
```

If you need to add Git configuration, you just have to call

```
git config <some option>
```

Did it help you ?

Best regards

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. It definitely helped to hear what I suspected but didn't know for sure: that I should never write directly into the `.git` directory.  I have added more information to my question to make it clearer. Is commit what I need in my case?

Comment: I Don't know what you wanna do with this repo but adding your config duplication to the working tree means committing this .config file.